# cURL - Getting partial data on receiver (400 bad request)

Tags: xml, http, post, curl

I have a program that posts some xml data using cURL over http to the cloud. Just before performing curl_easy_perform() when I print that data to console that looks OK ,but on receiving side the xml is corrupted, either it is truncated or mangled. I am not able to figure out the reason since the problem is intermittent

XML sent :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><plugin><macAddress>08863B6CAEF8</macAddress><serialNumber>221212K01008A4</serialNumber><friendlyName>WeMo Switch</friendlyName><udnName>uuid:Socket-1_0-221212K01008A4</udnName><homeId>700511319</homeId><deviceType>Switch</deviceType><status>0</status><statusTS>1425892983</statusTS><firmwareVersion>WeMo_WW_2.00.8337.DVT-OWRT-SNS</firmwareVersion><fwUpgradeStatus>4</fwUpgradeStatus><signalStrength>96</signalStrength><attributeLists action="notify"><attribute><name>RuleAutoOffTime</name><value>0</value></attribute></attributeLists></plugin>
```

On receiver side I am getting this

```
tatusTS>1423077095</statusTS><firmwareVersion>WeMo_WW_2.00.7284.PVT</firmwareVersion><fwUpgradeStatus>4</fwUpgradeStatus><signalStrength>100</signalStrength><eventDuration>123</eventDuration><startTime>1378302633</startTime></plugin>
```

Here is the code snippet that is carrying out the above task

```
//Actual data being sent is inData[] array in *pUsrAppData

// user Application data
typedef struct userAppData {
  char url[SIZE_256B]; // url to which the session needs to be established
  KeyValue keyVal[SIZE_32B]; // html content heaer specifying the key and value
  int keyValLen;      //Number of pairs in keyValue
  char inData[DATA_BUF_LEN]; // file path or data which needs to be sent 
  int inDataLength; // length of data which needs to be sent, if <=0 then indata contains file path
                    // or if it is >0 then it should contain length of data in indata
  int inDataCount; /**This is added for thread access problem 400 and 500 bad request*/
  char *outData; // pointer to the data which is received in response from the server
  //char outData[DATA_BUF_LEN]; // pointer to the data which is received in response from the server
  int outDataLength; // data length of the out data
  char outHeader[DATA_BUF_LEN]; // pointer to the header data which is received in response from the server
  int outHeaderLength; // data length of the out header data
  int httpsFlag; //Flag to identify https or http, should be set to 1 for https and 0 for http
  int disableFlag; //Flag to identify whether error handling is to be enabled or disabled 
  int partNumber; //Specifies the current file part 
  char eTag[SIZE_4B][SIZE_128B]; // eTag for file uploads
  char mac[KEY_BUF_LEN]; //max address used internally for posting transaction info for PUT case
  char cookie_data[KEY_VAL_LEN];
  int outResp; //Response value in outHeader
  int nStatusCode;      //HTTP Status Code
}UserAppData;


// user session data
typedef struct userAppSessionData {
  int sessionId;  // id corresponding to the session created
  CURL * curl; // pointer to curl SessionHandle structure 
}UserAppSessionData;

typedef struct webSessionListNode{
  UserAppData *pUsrAppData;
  UserAppSessionData *pUsrAppSsnData;
}WebSessionListNode;


  WebSessionListNode *pWebSsnListNode = NULL;




  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_URL, pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppData->url);   

  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);



  /* specify we want to POST data */
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

  /* Write and header callback */
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData);
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData);
  /* verbose debug output option */
  curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);



    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);
    /* pointer to pass to our read function */
    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppData);
    /* Set the expected POST size. */
    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)(pUsrAppData->inDataLength));
    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL,1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60L);/* 60 seconds - timeout when connecting to web server */
    curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60L);/* 60 seconds  - read timeout */
    res = curl_easy_perform(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl);

    //Here, xml being print is always sane
  APP_LOG("HTTPSWRAPPER", LOG_DEBUG, "Sent XML is :  %s\n", pUsrAppData->inData);
```

The cURL version I am using is 7.29 and buffer I am using to store the data is of sufficient length.

Comment: You should post the code that actually sends the data.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP if I may ask? Looks more like C, doesn't it? Maybe the code on the receiving side is missing? and that is PHP? Also the read_callback isn't part of the question which most likely is the cause of problems ... .

Answer (score 0):

Since (apparently) your POST data is a simple `\0` terminated string instead of a stream, you can use the following:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, pUsrAppData->inData);
```

instead of the calls to:

```
curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppData);
curl_easy_setopt(pWebSsnListNode->pUsrAppSsnData->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)(pUsrAppData->inDataLength));
```

Also, depending on the receiver you may need to add an explicit call to:

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, struct curl_slist *headers);
```

to set the `Content-Type` header to something like `application/xml`.

Comment: It will be just alternative to do POST operation... right? or it will impact data transmission to some extent

Comment: it is a simple alternative to do POST; it will not impact data transmission but I'm guessing your `read_callback` is incorrect so it would avoid calling that routine

Comment: I will test changes on endurance setup ...if it works, will accept your answer.